# Powershell Batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file for my below powershell script. I want it to ask Group name first and then run the PS script.

```
Get-AdGroupMember -identity "GroupName" | select name | Export-csv -path C:\members.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Any leads please?

Comment: There [is](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) `set /p `, but why not use `Read-Host` in the Poewrshell part?

Comment: You only have Powershell code in your question.  What is the batch file you are referring to?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Answer (score 1):

If you want Ps to ask, the consider using read-host like mentioned by @vonPryz.

```
$groupname = read-host "Please enter the Group Name:" # this bit will save the input to a variable.
Get-AdGroupMember -identity $groupname  | select name | Export-csv -path C:\members.csv -NoTypeInformation
```